# Stackdriver logs - getting stats

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

Is there a way to find stats like how many requests were responded with status=200 and how many with status=500 after filtering logs by specific text ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [Log Based Metric](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/) to track stats from now on, but it is not possible to have the metric filled from existing logs or to get the stats via a one-off query.